# Spontaneous Photograph

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, phrase-requests

Is there an expression for a spontaneously un-posed snapshot/photograph? The ones taken by surprise, that give that 'natural look'?

Comment: "Candid" is the usual adjective, though it carries a whole host of often-conflicting connotations.

Comment: There's also nothing outright wrong with "Spontaneous photograph"

Comment: What about un-posed itself?

Answer (score 2):

**snapshot** — an informal photograph that is taken quickly ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snapshot))

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Silenus, a *candid* picture, if you are looking for an adjective.

An *impromptu* might work in context, if you need a single word noun:

> An impromptu is something produced or done without care or planning.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impromptu

Also, check out the heading of this news item for real-world usage:

http://www.oxfordmail.co.uk/news/headlines/11010118.Impromptu_picture_proves_a_hit_in_global_competition/

Comment: I don't think *impromptu* conveys what the OP is looking for. After all, it's possible to have an entire [impromptu photo shoot](https://www.google.com/search?q="impromptu+photo+shoot").

Comment: I disagree. I think in certain contexts they are synonymous:
http://www.imore.com/how-to-take-incredible-impromptu-photos-kids-iphone 


And a snippet from the National Geographic:
Posed group pictures can be nice, but sometimes the really memorable shots are the *candid ones*. Learn the secrets to capturing *impromptu moments*.

Comment: Hmm. At your first link, many of those impromptu photos are *not* candid shots; but it's possible that they are indeed what the OP has in mind.